# Rails with Jenkins and TEST:Unit too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jenkins

I have a Rails 3 app that has around 2000 tests with around 4000 assertions.

There are "normal" Unit and Functional tests using Test::Unit, Mocha and Shoulda. Everything works fine, it is taking less than 5 minutes to run all the tests.

I setup a Jenkins instance to run the tests, everything works, but if there are any failures, the build is still a SUCCESS and no FAILURE triggers are triggered.

I read that I need to publish the test results as JUnit test results, meaning to convert them to XML. I added gem 'ci_reporter' and changed the command in Jenkins to run tests from

```
bundle exec rake test
```

to

```
bundle exec rake ci:setup:testunit test
```

All works, I have build marked as failed if some tests are failing, but running all the tests takes now 3 hours and 40 minutes. I can't work with that.

Is there something that I can do to have the output converted to xml faster? Why is this huge difference from less than 5 minutes to almost 4 hours for just putting some XMLs into a folder?

Comment: I do not have an answer, just a guess: I use Python and nosetest at work and I had a similar problem: using xml output prevents running tests in parallel and it of course slows it down.

Comment: FWIW, I notice the same thing with ci_reporter_minitest, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to make it run in a reasonable amount of time with ci:setup:test, so I am using an alternative solution. This is my Jenkins job configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
source ~/.bashrc
rvm use 2.1.1
rvm gemset use my_gemset
cd project_path
export RAILS_ENV=test
bundle install 
[ -d "coverage" ] && rm -rf coverage
mkdir coverage
#bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
T1=`bundle exec rake test`
T2=3
echo "$T1"
T3=`echo "$T1" |  grep -c '\([[:space:]]0[[:space:]]\)failures,\1errors'`
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo " __________ "
echo "|          |"
echo "| Summary: |"
echo "|__________|"
echo "            "
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "$T1" | grep -E '[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{0,4}[[:space:]]failures,[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{0,4}[[:space:]]errors'
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
if [ "$T3" = "$T2" ]; then echo "SUCCESS - All tests passed"; else exit -1; fi
```

Basically I am grepping for for failure/errors and mark build as failed if there are any. Also, in post build I have a job that send emails with console output attached. It is not ideal, but it works and it is fast